# Java code to check if two cron expressions have overlap times

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to check if two cron expressions overlap at any point:

```
cron1 = "0 0 10 1/1 ? "; //everyday at 10am

cron2 = "0 0 10 ? MON "; //every monday at 10am
```

The two expressions above overlap on Monday at 10AM.
Is there some way to determine if two cron expressions overlap? You can assume the expressions are valid and passed in a string format.

I checked libraries such as [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) and [cron-utils](http://cron-utils.com/), but these only go so far as to check if two cron expressions are equivalent or give me the next execution time.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  What problem are you having with your current attempt?  How are these cron expressions generated?  Are there any limitations, or should it take any valid cron expression?  Please see [ask].

Comment: updated question with relevant info.

Comment: Is the definition of an overlap the exact same start time?  I suppose you would have to process the cron strings into some logical format and determine if there's overlap in the logical format.

Comment: Here overlap implies the cron schedules having the same start time at any point time. In the example above there would be an overlap on monday at 10am